# Uploading a torrent, many connections overtime, no downloads

Tags: linux, connection, bittorrent, upload

As the title says, I'm uploading some torrents but one in particular has an OK amount of downloaders to seed to, I'm getting a nice ammount of connections, and not uploading a single bit. [a few connected peers, no uploading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tm6Jg.png)

I just fail to understand why it refuses to upload. qBittorrent on linux.

Comment: you have port forwarding set up in the router correctly?

Comment: it's set up correctly as sometimes it will upload, it's just that it decides not to even when people are requesting download

Comment: Peers may show up but are not downloading if they pause the download they will still show up as a peer, you just need to let it run for weeks.